Shopify section not displaying background image
I have a custom shopify section to display certain products. I cannot get the background image to display. Below is the css and html being used in the section liquid file.
.pimage1{background-image: url('https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/16/2500/1667.jpg?hmac=uAkZwYc5phCRNFTrV_prJ_0rP0EdwJaZ4ctje2bY7aE');transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;height:300px;width:100%;}

<div class="featured-product">
    <div class="product-wrap">
        <a href="{{ product_one.url }}" title="{{ product_one.title }}">
            <div class="pimage1"></div>
            <h3>{{ product_one.title }}</h3>
            <div class="price">{{ product_one.price | money }}</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


Your hyperlink tag  is not properly closed on line 3, add > and see if that fixes the issue.
<a href="{{ product_one.url }}" title="{{ product_one.title }}">


Thanks for responding. That was a copy and paste error. In the actual code the anchor tag is closed.
